# accessing addressused in activityparty when using javascript

Tags: dynamics-crm

When I create a new Activityparty with:

```
// Create an activity party for the email TO
Entity[] activityPartyTo = new Entity[1];
activityPartyTo[0] = new Entity("activityparty");
activityPartyTo[0]["addressused"] = "john@email.com"
activityPartyTo[0]["partyid"] = new EntityReference("contact", to.Get(executionContext).Id);
email["to"] = activityPartyTo;
```

I'm referencing a specific contact, but I don't want to use the default emailaddress1 or emailaddress2 in contact so i set "addressused".

The question is where can I access it in javascript? This code gives me all activityparties but the only attribute I see is name and type

```
    var party = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("to");
    var members = party.getValue();

    for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        // Contact
        if (members[i].type == 2) {
            alert("Contact Id: " + members[i].id + " Name: " + members[i].name + " addressused: " + members[i].addressused);
        }
    }
```

but addressused is undefined, can someone tell me where addressused is stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get the Activity Party **id** from the lookup field you will need to execute the following request to the WebAPI to get the `addressused`(the retrieve method can't be used with this entity so that's why I'm using a filter):

```
GET /api/data/v9.0/activityparties?$select=addressused&$filter=activitypartyid eq YOURID
```

If you're using v9 you can use the following code:

```
Xrm.WebApi.retrieveMultipleRecords("activityparty", "?$select=addressused&$filter=activitypartyid eq 04c31532-4ae5-e511-80fe-00155d09ab01").then(
    function success(result) {
        for (var i = 0; i < result.entities.length; i++) {
            console.log(result.entities[i].addressused);
        }                    
    },
    function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }
);
```